# Lambda representing a getter method from either a parent class or a child class

Tags: java, lambda

I have some code below representing a parent and child Pojo, and a simple validator that pulls two values off them representing ranges, to verify that start < end. I want to validator to be generic enough that it can accept two field getter methods at construction time, and then be able to be passed a POJO to perform the range check on. However, I have been unable to get this to type check properly. I have tried having the validator constructor taking all of the following:

```
Function<Pojo, Integer> //Fails on constructing vlad2 - "Incompatible types in lambda expression: Expected Pojo but found ExtendedPojo".

Function<? extends Pojo, Integer> //Fails on getRangeStart.apply(pojo) - "(capture<? extends Pojo>) in Function cannot be applied to Pojo"

Function<Object, Integer> //Fails on constructing both vlad and vlad2 - "Incompatible types in lambda expression: Expected Object but found ExtendedPojo"
```

Code:

```
import java.util.function.Function;

class Pojo {

  private Integer rangeOneStart;
  private Integer rangeOneEnd;

  public Pojo(Integer rangeOneStart, Integer rangeOneEnd) {
    this.rangeOneStart = rangeOneStart;
    this.rangeOneEnd = rangeOneEnd;
  }

  public Integer getRangeOneStart() {
    return rangeOneStart;
  }

  public Integer getRangeOneEnd() {
    return rangeOneEnd;
  }
}

class ExtendedPojo extends Pojo {
  private Integer rangeTwoStart;
  private Integer rangeTwoEnd;

  public ExtendedPojo(Integer rangeOneStart, Integer rangeOneEnd, Integer rangeTwoStart, Integer rangeTwoEnd) {
    super(rangeOneStart, rangeOneEnd);
    this.rangeTwoStart = rangeTwoStart;
    this.rangeTwoEnd = rangeTwoEnd;
  }

  public Integer getRangeTwoStart() {
    return rangeTwoStart;
  }

  public Integer getRangeTwoEnd() {
    return rangeTwoEnd;
  }
}

interface SomeValidatorInterface<T> {
  boolean isValid(T obj);
}

class MyValidator implements SomeValidatorInterface<Pojo> {

  private Function<Pojo, Integer> getRangeStart;
  private Function<Pojo, Integer> getRangeEnd;

  MyValidator(Function<Pojo, Integer> getRangeStart, Function<Pojo, Integer> getRangeEnd) {
    this.getRangeStart = getRangeStart;
    this.getRangeEnd = getRangeEnd;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isValid(Pojo pojo) {
    Integer start = getRangeStart.apply(pojo);
    Integer end = getRangeEnd.apply(pojo);
    return end > start;
  }
}

class Main {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ExtendedPojo pojo = new ExtendedPojo(1,2,3,4);
    MyValidator vlad = new MyValidator(Pojo::getRangeOneStart, Pojo::getRangeOneEnd);
    System.out.println(vlad.isValid(pojo));

    MyValidator vlad2 = new MyValidator(ExtendedPojo::getRangeTwoStart, ExtendedPojo::getRangeTwoEnd);
    System.out.println(vlad2.isValid(pojo));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the validator is being used per instance just provide a specific instance method as `Supplier<Integer>`

```
MyValidator(Supplier<Integer> getRangeStart, Supplier<Integer> getRangeEnd) {
    this.getRangeStart = getRangeStart;
    this.getRangeEnd = getRangeEnd;
}

// ...

ExtendedPojo pojo = new ExtendedPojo(1,2,3,4);
MyValidator vlad = new MyValidator(pojo::getRangeOneStart, pojo::getRangeOneEnd);
```

If you don't want to use such specific construction you need to move the range getter to the common interface or at least the `Pojo` class and override this in `ExtendedPojo`

Comment: I would like to use one validator for many instances.